# Mysql won't allow me to create new user gives ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.role_edges' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I have been trying to connect a REST api to a mysql db. I can do this over localhost but when I try to give access to a host IP I get an error about permission denied. After researching things it seems the solution to this is create a new user and grant access to localhost and the IP like so in the mysql shell... (There should only be one * before the . Stack wouldn't let me pot it correctly)

CREATE USER ‘Name’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON **.* TO ‘Name’@’localhost’ WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER ‘Name’@’IP’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON **.* TO ‘vScopeUserName’@’IP’ WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

When I enter the first command I get this error:
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.role_edges' doesn't exist

I can't find much info on this, if anyone knows anything or has suggestions it is much appreciated. Also I'm using Node.js on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you upgrade MySQL recently?

Comment: no, I didn't change anything between being able to create the user the first time and it giving me this error. I only had tried running the REST api and sending it a POST request.

Comment: That's odd as that's an internal MySQL table. I mentioned upgrading because sometimes that happens automatically for you if you have a background update process running.